# Merging two files, why does it add a new line at the end? C programming

Tags: c, file, merge, line

This function merges two files into third file line by line. I tested it and when it's merged, at the end of the third it adds an empty new line (first file has 4 lines of text, second file 5 lines). How do I get rid of it? Thank you! :)

```
 void fileMerge()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
    char line1[MAX], line2[MAX]; 

    fp1 = fopen(fileName1, "r"); 
    fp2 = fopen(fileName2, "r");
    fp3 = fopen(fileName3, "w+"); 

    while ((!feof(fp1)) && (!feof(fp2)))
    {
        fgets(line1, MAX, fp1);
        if (!feof(fp1)) 
        {
            fprintf(fp3, "%s", line1);
        }

        fgets(line2, MAX, fp2); 
        if (!feof(fp2)) 
        {
            fprintf(fp3, "%s", line2);
        }

        strcpy(line1, "\0"); 
        strcpy(line2, "\0"); 
    }

    fclose(fp1); 
    fclose(fp2); 
    fclose(fp3); 

    printf("\n Files merged...\n");
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your `input` and `output` files?

Comment: Better yet, hex dumps of two short simple files.

Comment: What do you mean by an "empty new line"? My test files have 4 and 5 lines, every line ends with `newline`. In the text editor, the last line *looks like an empty new line* but each line has only one `newline`. The same goes for the output file - no "extra" `newline` is present.

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree. As the name says, a `newline` starts a new line and is not needed to terminate a line. But of course the problem might be his files having such `newline`s.

Comment: @Hermann Döppes *none* of my text files ever begins with a `newline` unless the first line is blank. `newline` is a terminator. The final blank line in the text editor, is to show where to type next. OTOH if the last line in my textfile does not end with a `newline` there is no blank line in the text editor. Note that `fgets()` *appends* any `newline`, it does not prepend it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay, I correct myself: `newline` separates an old line from a new one. It is neither needed to specify a first line (we all know it will be there) nor to end the last (that's what `EOF` is for). Anyway, this doesn't add to the question so we probably should stop now.

Comment: @HermannDöppes: not ending the last line of a text file with an **end of line sequence** is very poor style.  Many if not most programs do not handle this special case gracefully.  On unix systems, including Mac/OS, this end of line sequence is the `LF` byte.  On Windows, the dubious `CR LF` sequence inherited from `CP/M` is used. `newline` is the C name for the `\n` escape that is converted by the C library into the appropriate end of line sequence for the host system.

Answer (score 1):

You open the output file as `"w+"`, you do not need the `+`.

Testing the end of file with `feof()` is bound to fail.  You should instead check the return value of `fgets()`.

`strcpy(line1, "\0");` just copies a single null byte at the start of `line1`.  use `line1[0] = '\0';` for this.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void fileMerge(void) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
    char line1[MAX], line2[MAX]; 
    int need_line_feed = 0;

    fp1 = fopen(fileName1, "r");
    fp2 = fopen(fileName2, "r");
    fp3 = fopen(fileName3, "w");

    if (fp1 && fp2 && fp3) {
        for (;;) {
            if (fp1) {
                if (fgets(line1, MAX, fp1)) {
                    if (need_line_feed)
                        putc('\n', fp3);
                    fputs(line1, fp3);
                    need_line_feed = !strchr(line1, '\n');
                } else {
                    fclose(fp1);
                    fp1 = NULL;
                }
            }
            if (fp2) {
                if (fgets(line2, MAX, fp2)) {
                    if (need_line_feed)
                        putc('\n', fp3);
                    fputs(line2, fp3);
                    need_line_feed = !strchr(line2, '\n');
                } else {
                    fclose(fp2);
                    fp2 = NULL;
                }
            }
            if (!fp1 && !fp2) {
                printf("\n Files merged...\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (fp1) fclose(fp1);
    if (fp2) fclose(fp2);
    if (fp3) fclose(fp3);
}
```

It handles the special case where `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` do not end with a linefeed.  But is does not handle lines longer than `MAX-1` characters correctly.  For this, an alternative approach using `getc()` and `putc()` seems preferable.

EDIT: I implemented your peculiar semantics: the merged file does not end with a linefeed if the longer of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` does not.

Comment: This program fails when one file doesn't have any text left, but the second file still has some. My first file has 4 lines and the second one has 5 lines. 

file1.txt contents:
1)
2)
3)
4)

file2.txt contents:
a)
b)
c)
d)
e)

result.txt contents:

1)
a)
2)
b)
3)
c)
4)d)
e)

edit: sorry can't describe it here correctly because comments in here don't allow new lines

Comment: @darijus: you did not give a precise specification of the expected behavior when a file has fewer lines than the other. Is `1) a) 2) b) 3) c) 4) d) e)` the expected behavior?  If yes, then the code above does exactly that.  I edited it for clarity.

Comment: It does handle the situation where both files do not end with a linefeed but this time it creates an empty new line after the last line. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @darijus: What do you call an empty new line?  The fact that your editor lets you put the cursor at the end of the file on an empty line does not mean the line exists, it is a handy way for you to create this line.  Which editor are you using?

Comment: By saying an empty new line I mean after the "e)" line there is another line without any contents. Just a new line. Is it possible to get rid of it? My program that I posted has the same problem. I need to have no blank lines because after that I have to reverse file contents and when it reverses the blank line is at the top.

Comment: any ideas how do get rid of it? :/

Comment: How do you reverse the file?  transposing lines or transposing characters?  you can reverse the file line by line by using `tail -r < myfile > outputfile`

Comment: I reverse the whole file. Is there no way to get rid of that new line?

Comment: Be more precise: do you reverse the file byte by byte?  What is your OS?  On windows, CR LF will be reversed as LF CR, which is not a proper end of line.  What code do you use to reverse the file?  As for the final linefeed, if you do not want it, do not add it unless the other file still has lines.  I'll modify the answer for your peculiar need.

Comment: You are amazing! Yes I do reverse it byte by byte. I move the pointer to the end of fthe file and start reading it from there. Windows OS. How would you reverse it line by line?

Comment: You could reverse it line by line by reading it line by line into an array of dynamically allocated lines, and then writing out the lines in reverse order.  The same can be done byte by byte: read the whole file in an array and write byte by byte from the end.  The way you do it, using `fseek(f,-2,SEEK_CUR);` after each `getc(f);` is not reliable unless the file was opened in `"rb"` mode, which will cause the problem I described earlier: invalid line endings.

Answer (score 1):

to chqrlie's reply:

```
file1.txt contents:

1)
2)
3)
4)

file2.txt contents:

a)
b)
c)
d)
e)


result.txt contents:

1)
a)
2)
b)
3)
c)
4)d)
e)
```

Comment: OK, I understand: `file1.txt`'s last line does not end with a linefeed.  I'll fix my answer for this special case.